# Accessing AnyCodable values with @dynamicMemberLookup

Tags: swift, persistence, codable, swift4.2, untyped-variables

[Objc.io](https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E31-mutating-untyped-dictionaries) has a great talk on easily mutating untyped Dictionaries, but the problem is you can't easily persist them. I think the talk may have been released before `@dynamicMemberLookup` was introduced.

[AnyCodable](https://github.com/Flight-School/AnyCodable) looks awesome for easily encoding/decoding/persisting simple Dictionaries but you can't easily access the Dictionary members.

I was wondering if it's possible/feasible to add `@dynamicMemberLookup` functionality found in Swift 4.2 (eg: in [this example](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0195-dynamic-member-lookup.md#example-usage)) to AnyCodable and, if so, how? **The end goal would be to access/mutate an untyped Array or Dictionary *and* persist them.**

So, I tried doing it like this:

```
@dynamicMemberLookup
public struct AnyCodable: Codable {
    public let value: Any

    public init<T>(_ value: T?) {
        self.value = value ?? ()
    }

    subscript(dynamicMember member: String) -> AnyCodable? {
        switch self.value {
        case let dictionary as [String: Any?]:
            return AnyCodable(dictionary[member])
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Given the example Dictionary from `AnyCodable`:

```
let dictionary: [String: AnyEncodable] = [
    "boolean": true,
    "integer": 1,
    "double": 3.14159265358979323846,
    "string": "string",
    "array": [1, 2, 3],
    "nested": [
        "a": "alpha",
        "b": "bravo",
        "c": "charlie"
    ]
]
```

If I do:

```
if let nested = dictionary["nested"] {
    print("nested a:", nested.a)
}
```

it outputs: `nested a: Optional(AnyCodable(Optional("alpha")))` which is almost there! But I want to be able to simply write `dictionary?.nested?.a` OR `dictionary?.array?[1]` rather than unwrap `nested` first with `if let nested = dictionary["nested"]`. *And* I want to be able to mutate it, eg: `dictionary?.nested?.a? = "beta"`.

I can't figure out how to get it across the finish line though. I'd obviously need to add `case let array as [Any]:` etc. and maybe change the subscript to include getter/setters? But what else am I missing?

I know you're probably "not supposed to use Dictionaries that way" and create a full-blown custom-typed model and all that, but this is for a small project where going that route would be overkill. So please don't answer with "model your data differently". I want to combine these two existing methods of accessing/persisting untyped dictionaries or arrays into one.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I had it mostly covered.

The first problem is, that you work with a dictionary. You can add **@dynamicMemberLookup** only to the main definition, so you can't do it on the dictionary definition. Try this:

```
let dictionary: [String: AnyEncodable] = [ ... ]
let easierToUse = AnyCodable(dictionary)
```

So considering code below, is it what you needed? :

```
let dictionary: [String: AnyCodable] = [
    "boolean": true,
    "integer": 1,
    "double": 3.14159265358979323846,
    "string": "string",
    "array": [1, 2, 3],
    "nested": [
        "a": "alpha",
        "b": "bravo",
        "c": "charlie",
        "array": [
            1,
            2,
            [
                "a": "alpha",
                "b": "bravo",
                "c": "deep charlie"
            ]
        ],
    ]
]
let easierToUse: AnyCodable = AnyCodable(dictionary)

if let value = easierToUse.nested?.a {
    print(value) // prints "alpha"
}

if let value = easierToUse.nested?.array?[2]?.c {
    print(value) // prints "deep charlie"
}

if let value = easierToUse.nested?.array?[2]?.c?.value as? String {
    print(value) // prints "deep charlie"
}
```

I had to update your classes a bit, as you forgot that it is all wrapped on every level:

```
// Helper to handle out of bounds on array with nil
extension Array {
    subscript (safe index: Int) -> Element? {
        return indices ~= index ? self[index] : nil
    }
}

@dynamicMemberLookup
public struct AnyCodable: Codable {
    public let value: Any

    public init<T>(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    public init<T>(_ value: T?) {
        self.value = value ?? ()
    }

    subscript(dynamicMember member: String) -> AnyCodable? {
        switch self.value {
        case let anyCodable as AnyCodable:
            return anyCodable[dynamicMember: member]
        case let dictionary as [String: Any?]:
            return AnyCodable(dictionary[member] ?? nil)
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    subscript(index: Int) -> AnyCodable? {
        switch self.value {
        case let anyCodable as AnyCodable:
            return anyCodable[index]
        case let array as [Any]:
            return AnyCodable(array[safe: index])
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! That does seem to work! What about setting? eg: `easierToUse.nested?.array?[2]?.c = "not charlie"`

Comment: Would this entire setup need to be a class instead of a struct in order to use `set { ... }` inside the dynamicMemberLookup subscripts? Since `AnyCodable` members are value referenced? :o

Comment: You can keep it struct probably, I will try to play with mutating stuff today. It is a bit harder, as for getters you've already done most of the work

Comment: @taber It is getting a bit too big to paste it into stacoverflow responses. I forked original repo, and added all dynamicMemberLookup stuff. Added tests for getting/setting values, you can check it out at: https://github.com/amichnia/AnyCodable

Comment: Ah, nice! Maybe I'm using it wrong, but if I change and try saving the example dict, I get an `AnyCodable value cannot be encoded` error. Are you able to save & load the example dict typed as AnyCodable? My test code:
`var easierToUse: AnyCodable = [...example dict here...]
easierToUse.nested?.array?[2]?.c = "NOT charles"
do {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(easierToUse)
    try data.write(to: fileUrl)
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}`
If I _don't_ change it, it saves fine. (Shouldn't AnyCodable be encodable & decodable?)

Comment: Good point, I will add write and read to tests. Could you post this as an issue in github repo? Since mattt does not seem to accept any pr to the original one, I think I 'll use my fork for now.

Comment: Github doesn't let people add issues to forks, apparently. Sigh.